# how to know the correct path of my file in web service ( File Exception )

Tags: java, file, service, web, client

I am working with a java web service, the service includes methods that should read data from file, and the client of the service has to send the path of the file as a String, when I try to do that and send the path, I got trouble and the error was:

```
  readFile.client.IOException_Exception: src\rm.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

( The file is exist in the src folder - the source code folder -

is there any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put the file in your WEB-Inf and you can access it with "filename".

But you could add a method witch let the client know which files are available and return this path to the server, then it does not affect the client if you change the name or other things.

Comment: I have tried the first solution, but It did not work. so how can I know the available files to send the path to the server

Comment: Can you please share the snipped code from your server and client code